# Localizing arrays with different lengths for different locales in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, localization

I want to localize an array with say... 5 strings. But for the target language I only want it to have 3 strings. For example if I want to display 5 images in English, but only 3 different ones in French.

Since if I localize the strings I am declaring a value for strings that don't exist in the other language, how would I go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: what about put empty string in your other language localization?

Comment: That woud interfere with string.count and other bits of convenient code. But you did give me an idea if there is no other way. I can do what you said and then loop through them and remove all empty strings! Thanks Seto!